# How to ready a file using python, where data is appended continuously?

Tags: python, stream

Assuming a server dumps logs to a file and we need to read last 100 lines.
In the meantime, the file is loaded with more lines.
How to tackle this kind of cases?

Comment: It isn't very clear in what requirements need to be met. For all you know, you could just dump all the log contents into an array or a string and append to it, and just flush all the contents later.

Comment: You might want to look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file), and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407834/python-detect-log-file-rotation-while-watching-log-file-for-modification/44411621#44411621).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you shouldn't do is dump all the contents of the file into a string. That would be horrible, as log files can get up to sizes of 100 MB. If you were only allowed one file handler, what I would recommend is to have a queue to write the lines, and every once in a while, dump the lines into the log. In the free time, it can read the last 100 lines.